# Connect to UTF-8 SSID in Windows 8.1

Tags: windows, wireless-networking, windows-8.1, unicode

How can you connect to an SSID on Windows 8.1 that has an emoji (or any UTF-8-encoded, multibyte character) in it?

Is there some way I can specify the bytes in the UTF-8-encoded emoji, because copy-and-pasting doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

It works if you manually add the SSID and then paste in the Latin1 (ISO-8859-1) encoded bytes. This means instead of seeing a single square (undisplayable character) in place of the emoji, you'll see 4 Latin1 characters.

1. Go to Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Network and Sharing Center
2. Set Up a Connection or Network
3. Manually connect to a wireless network
4. Paste your Latin1-encoded bytes into Network name
5. Finish the process as usual (e.g., fill in your Security key, hit Next, etc.)